# convert a dataframe to a square dataframe

Tags: r

Say I have the following df:

```
library (tidyverse)
    df <- tribble(
      ~ID, ~V1, ~V2,~V3,
      '1',   NA,1, NA,
      '2',   1,1,NA,
      '3',   1,NA,NA,
      '4',   NA,NA,1,
      '5', 1,1,1,
      '6',NA,NA,1,
      '7',1,NA,1
    )
```

Now I’d like to sum the values for V2 and V3 separately when V1=1, and correspondingly for The other variables. 
I´d like to obtain the following df-

```
   df2 <- tribble(
      ~Var,~V1,~V2,~V3,
      'V1',0,2,1,
      'V2',2,0,1,
      'V3',1,1,0
    )
```

Comment: What is the logic here? I initially thought it was sum of the intersecting elements between the three columns.

Comment: Tried to explain it in words as well

Comment: Must you have `V1,V2.V3 = NA` in the original dataframe? Why not convert them to 0, make things easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
nm1 <- names(df)[-1]
set_names(nm1, nm1) %>% 
    map_df(~ df %>% 
    filter(!!rlang::sym(.x)==1) %>% 
    select(-ID) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(!! .x := 0), .id = 'Var')
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Var      V1    V2    V3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 V1     0     2.00  2.00
#2 V2     2.00  0     1.00
#3 V3     2.00  1.00  0
```

Comment: Both solutions do the trick and I'd gladly accept both. Dplyr solution is slightly less terse than base R so I'll give credit to its legilibility.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `do.call` and `mapply` is as:

```
do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x){
  v <- colSums(df[!is.na(df[,x]) & df[,x]==1,-1], na.rm = TRUE)
  v[x-1] <- 0
  v
}, 2:4, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

#      V1 V2 V3
# [1,]  0  2  2
# [2,]  2  0  1
# [3,]  2  1  0
```

**Note:** The expected output for `(1,3)` and `(3,1)` is not matching with value mentioned in question. Perhaps OP needs to very by those 2 values.